# Converting HTTP POST from curl (PHP) to HttpURLConnection (Java)

Tags: java, php, web-services, httpurlconnection, web-deployment

I tried to convert the below PHP code (taken from https://www.cryptocoincharts.info/tools/api) to java

```
// define pairs
$post = array("pairs" => "ltc_usd,ppc_btc");

// fetch data
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.cryptocoincharts.info/tradingPairs");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$rawData = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// decode to array
$data = json_decode($rawData);

// show data
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    echo "Price of ".$row->id.": ".$row->price."\n";
    echo "Trade this pair on ".$row->best_market."\n";
}
echo "</pre>";
```

**Java Code**

```
    URL url = new URL("http://api.cryptocoincharts.info/tradingPairs");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    //  CURLOPT_POST
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    // CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

    String postData = "ltc_usd,ppc_btc";
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(postData.length()));

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);

    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    output.writeBytes(postData);
    output.close();

    // "Post data send ... waiting for reply");
    int code = con.getResponseCode(); // 200 = HTTP_OK
    System.out.println("Response    (Code):" + code);
    System.out.println("Response (Message):" + con.getResponseMessage());

    // read the response
    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
    int c;
    StringBuilder resultBuf = new StringBuilder();
    while ( (c = input.read()) != -1) {
        resultBuf.append((char) c);
    }
    input.close();
    System.out.println("resultBuf.toString() " + resultBuf.toString());
```

As per the API, after converting this to java I should get only the details of LTC and PPC details. Instead I am getting a strange Json with all trading pairs.

```
2 $post = array("pairs" => "ltc_usd,ppc_btc"); Posted the PHP code as I am not known the exact equivalent in Java
```

Could you please point out if my conversion from PHP to Java is correct ?

Comment: @Berger in this case the OP Java code is correct. He has a porting problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I see, the main difference between the two implementation is related to the `$post` variable.

In the PHP implementation `$post` is a key/value array but in Java I only see the value part.

I suggest to change the `postData` variable content into `pairs=ltc_usd,ppc_btc`

Comment: You are the man. Sitting with the issue for a long time. Thanks !

Comment: I think is an interesting question

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mentioned key part, only value is mentioned. And when we fetch data from PHP API, we have an associative array. If u want to display the output, u need to know the key and value of the particular associative array. 
And the InputStream and OutputStream should be inside try-resources

Answer (score 0):

you can try curl-to-java lib to convert curl php code to java code
https://github.com/jeffreyning/curl-to-java
demo like this 
    public Object curl(String url, Object postData, String method) {

```
    CurlLib curl = CurlFactory.getInstance("default");
    ch = curl.curl_init();
    curl.curl_setopt(ch, CurlOption.CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1000);
    curl.curl_setopt(ch, CurlOption.CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5000);
    curl.curl_setopt(ch, CurlOption.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl.curl_setopt(ch, CurlOption.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    String postDataStr = "key1=v1";

    curl.curl_setopt(ch, CurlOption.CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl.curl_setopt(ch, CurlOption.CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postDataStr);
    curl.curl_setopt(ch, CurlOption.CURLOPT_URL, "https://xxxx.com/yyy");
    Object html = curl.curl_exec(ch);
    Object httpCode = curl.curl_getinfo(ch, CurlInfo.CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if (httpCode != null && 200 == Integer.valueOf(httpCode.toString())) {
        return null;
    }
    return html;
}
```